# What is the meaning of empty export {} in vanilla javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

In the Google Maps Javascript API example, I see they had something like this in the HTML:

```html
<script type="module" src="./index.ts"></script>
```

and an empty export statement at the end of the TS/JS scripts.

```js
let map;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 8,
    });
}
window.initMap = initMap;
export {};
```

I don't see any examples or mentioning of empty exports on MDN, so I was wondering if anyone knew how it works. How does the script know to run it if the export is empty.

Comment: nothing magical about it.

Comment: I suspect this might be a TypeScript thing, it doesn't look to do anything in JS

Comment: The empty export is likely due to the usage of typescript, requiring all modules to have an import or export statement if [--isolatedModules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#non-module-files) is set. As to how does it know to run, it is a module imported via a script tag, and so will be executed as such. A function is defined and assigned to the window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like something in **TypeScript**; it has nothing to do with JavaScript.

---

If either of the cases below occurs, then you will need an `import`/`export` in the file.

1. The TypeScript file is being called with the flag below.

   ```
   --isolatedModules
   ```
2. The `tsconfig.json` file has the following key and value.

   ```json
   {
     "isolatedModules": true
   }
   ```

---

According to [*typescriptlang.org*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#isolatedModules), it states:

> If `isolatedModules` is set, all implementation files must be modules (which means it has some form of `import`/`export`). An error occurs if any file isn’t a module.

If you try to run the TypeScript file with the `--isolatedModules` flag, you get an error like below.

```
'index.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.
```

---

As the error states above, the simplest way to fix the issue without adding any unnecessary `import` statements and/or `export` statements, it is easiest to `export` an empty object (`{}`), like so.

```js
export {};
```

---

In summary, the empty object `export` will not do anything in JavaScript (or TypeScript, without the `--isolatedModules` flag). However, it comes in handy when running with the `--isolatedModules` flag.

The Google Maps JavaScript API example might be getting ready for this scenario, in case someone copied-and-pasted the code, so that they wouldn't get an error.